# Facebook Js Sdk, publish_actions not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm using javascript sdk and i have already send to review my publish_action , they are approved. Anyway i can't publish my post , the way i require the scope is this:

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{ 
...
}, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'});
```

When i try to publish the return error is:

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

It's true, because in the facebook modal login, appears only the permission to read information of the profile, no the permission to publish. How i can solve?

EDIT

i add my complete code to better explain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


/***FACEBOOK***/


    function fb_publish_Photo(immaginelink,idfoto){
             var testo_share= $("#share_text").text();


             var wallPost = {
                message: testo_share,
                link:immaginelink,
                picture:immaginelink

              };
              console.log(wallPost);
              FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {

                    console.log(response.error);
                  alert('Failure! ' + response.error + ' You may logout once and try again');


                } else {
                 // alert('Success! Post ID: ' + response.id);
                  var PostId=response.id;
                  if(response.id!=null && response.id!=''){

                     FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {



                        } else {
                            // do something...maybe show a login prompt
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
                  }
                }
                console.log(response);
              }, { scope: 'publish_actions'});
    }

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // Logged into your app and Facebook.
          //fb_login();

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        } else {

        }
      }

    function fb_login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {

            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                //console.log(response); // dump complete info
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
                user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

               FB.api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,name', function(response) {
                    //chiamata ajax per registrare/loggare l'utente
                    console.log(response);

                });

            } else {
                //user hit cancel button
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

            }
        }, {
            scope: 'publish_actions'
        });
    }
      // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
      // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
      // code below.
      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                                // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.4
          });

          // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
          // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
          // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
          // the callback you provide.  They can be:
          //
          // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
          // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
          // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
          //    your app or not.
          //
          // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
          });

      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    /***end FB***/
</script>
```

EDIT

This is the only ref i can find in facebook documentation:

```
function myFacebookLogin() {
  FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
}
```

or

```
FB.login(function(){
  // Note: The call will only work if you accept the permission request
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!'});
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

It seems simple, in login call i have to require permission, so why the publish permission dialog not appears in an approved app?

EDIT

[image]

this is a screen of my app permission

Comment: You are aware that publishing permission is only asked for on the _second_ “page” of the login dialog, right?

Comment: i can't see any second "page" on my login dialog. I have read that is suggested to divide scope, so i have also tried to request only email scope at login and then in FB.api only the publish_actions scope, but anything change

Comment: Passing a scope to FB.api is completely nonsense, I don’t know where newbies always come up with that ...

Comment: How did you get publish_actions approved, if you have not even implemented this yet in a working fashion? Showing how your app works is a requirement for permission review, so you can hardly have passed that if you did not even have this working yet …?

Comment: maybe this question is for how had approved my app, naturally the problem doesn't appear if i use a test user. Maybe they doesnt' see anything strange. Anyway i'm sorry for my newbie error, it's simply a try to solve the problem, i have probably misunderstood something.

Comment: If you can properly ask for the permission when you are using a user with a role in the app or a test user, but not when trying this with a “normal” user - then the most likely explanation is indeed that you did _not_ get the permission reviewed yet.

Comment: i have edited my question with a screenshoot of my app permission

Answer (score 0):

Publish_actions scope now seems to works correctly. I had two times scope request.